# Weblogic server failed to response under load

Tags: weblogic, httpclient, resteasy

We have a quite strange situation on my sight. Under load our WL 10.3.2 server failed to response. We are using RestEasy with HttpClient version 3.1 to coordinate with web service deployed as WAR.
What we have is a calculation process that run on 4 containers based on 4 physical machines and each of them send request to WL during calculation.

Each run we see a messages from HttpClient like this:

```
[THREAD1] INFO   I/O exception (org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException) caught     when processing request: The server OUR_SERVER_NAME failed to respond
[THREAD1] INFO   Retrying request
```

The HttpClient make several requests until get necessary data.

I want to understand why WL can refuse connections. I read about WL thread pool that process http request and found out that WL allocate separate thread to process web request and the numbers of threads is not bounded in default configuration. Also our server is configured *Maximum Open Sockets: -1* which means that the number of open sockets is unlimited.

From this thread I'd want to understand where the issue is? Is it on WL side or it's a problem of our business logic? Can you guys help to deeper investigate the situation.
What should I check more in order to understand that our WL server is configured to work with as much requests as we want?

Comment: Can you give more information? How large are the requests you're making? How many requests? Etc. Have you tried doing any testing with a tool like SoapUI to exercise service calls? Have you checked the Protocols -> HTTP settings for your server?

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp Requests is really small and contains only UUID of requested entity. For test purpose I am sending up to 40 requests per second but the real amount will be mush more.

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp Btw I am totally forgot about SoapUI tool. The settings for HTTP protocol also allows unlimited number of POST requests. Maybe it's a problem of HttpClient version. I made an investigation of the sources and found out that it trying to read response immediately after sending request. The reading from the stream throws the I/O exception. Maybe it will be better to use fourth HttpClient version.